# Update an existing figure window on a GUI button click

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I need to update a separate figure window iteratively on a button click on a GUI. Below is the relevant part of the my current code. It does not plot on the figure window. Hence creates a video with no plot in it. Thank you.

```
function pushbutton14_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton14 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.pushbutton14,'string','Creating...','enable','off');

folV = handles.folV;

files1T8 = dir(strcat(folV, '*.mat'));

numFiles1T8 = handles.numFiles1T8;
vAngle = handles.vAngle;
hAngle = handles.hAngle;

s = 1;
pS = 1;

vName = strcat(datestr(now,'yyyymmddHHMMSS'),'.avi');
handles.vName = vName;
guidata(hObject,handles);

writerObj = VideoWriter(strcat(folV,vName));
writerObj.FrameRate = 4;
open(writerObj);

az = 0;
el = 0;

for i = 1:numFiles1T8
    load(strcat(folV, files1T8(i).name));
    h = figure();
    scatter3(pc(1:s:size(pc,1),1), pc(1:s:size(pc,1),2), pc(1:s:size(pc,1),3),pS,pc(1:s:size(pc,1),4:6)/255,'filled');
    axis equal;
    axis off;
    view(az, el);

    f = getframe;
    fi = frame2im(f);
    writeVideo(writerObj,fi);
    clear pc;
    az = az + hAngle;
    el = el + vAngle;
    close(h);
end

close(writerObj);

set(handles.pushbutton14,'string','Done','enable','off');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `refreshdata`
http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/refreshdata.html?refresh=true

You could then so something like

```
axh = plot(xdata, ydata);
//... change the values of xdata and ydata
refreshdata(axh)
```